# async script src inside script tag, GDPR complilance google ads

Tags: javascript

I am doing the GDPR cookie compilance check and trying to load Google ads only if user accepts cookies.

I want to load google ads scripts only if a cookie does not exist.
So I want to do this:

```
    <script>
    if(cookieNo!="1"){
       <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-mycode"></script>
       window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
       function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
       gtag('js', new Date());

       gtag('config', 'AW-mycode');
       }
     <script>
```

Any idea how I can put the script tag inside the script tag?

Comment: What you want is load the script if user has accepted cookies right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, thanks

Comment: To me it looks like the two paragraphs are quite opposite? Can you please fix the text to correspond to what you need.

Comment: No, I think that is correct. if(cookieNo!="1"){ says if user has not clicked on decline which installs cookieNo. So if does not exists run code. Anyway has not tested yet

Comment: Also, the most of the pages are setting cookies anyway, no matter user accepts them or not. The GDPR statement only tells users that some cookies are set.

Comment: I know, but some cookies are legal to set, and others not.

Comment: However, you are asking "load Google ads only if user accepts cookies" ... right now, it would also load when user has not said yes or no to cookies.

Comment: I know that, thanks, will look how I do, maybe delete or change to cookie only if accept.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a snippet using which you can add a async script to the web page. Wrap this inside your condition and you are good to go.

```
const gScript = document.createElement('script');
gScript.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-mycode";
gScript.type = 'text/javascript';
gScript.onload = () => {
   console.log('Script has been fully loaded');
  // initlaize anything you want that needs to be done after script has loaded
  // Below code in your case
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
   gtag('js', new Date());
   gtag('config', 'AW-mycode');

};
gScript.async = true;
gScript.charset = 'utf-8';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(gScript);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I thought it would work, as I can see the cookies etc. ok, however the conversations does not appear in conversions in google ads. No idea why. After that code this script comes for the conversions:
<script>
gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-mycode'});
</script>

Any idea?

Comment: That might be an issue with you analytics script.. As the above piece of code is to just load the script into the document. I have it in one of my projects and it works fine.. Just cross check that all your gtag events are being triggered properly and if not you might have to trigger them manually

Comment: Not very good at this, I do not get it to work, however the solution below works. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
    if(cookieNo!="1"){
      var googleAds = document.createElement('script');
      googleAds.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-mycode";
      document.head.appendChild(googleAds);
      //Other code
}
</script>
```

Comment: This works for me, thanks a lot. First I tried the solution above, however solution above does not work for me.

Comment: @Helenp Happy to help!